# I have a problem when using the chrome extension deepl in editorjs

Tags: editorjs

I was using editorjs, but only when using the "header" and "pragraph" plugins,
I could not save.
After some research,
I found out that the problem occurs when using deepl as a chrome extension.

[block «paragraph» skipped because saved data is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHv22.png)

I looked in the chrome developer tools and found that
The "deeplL" dev was inserted below the pure text

[chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuJ2o.png)

If I turn off the deepl extension, I can save successfully, but
Instead of making the application user do this
Is there any way to get editojs to function properly with the deepL extension on?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. I just disabled the extension for now, but I am also looking for a way to prevent that from happening.